# Repeat animations cyclically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm creating a div to represent the past of the time during a day from the day to night; all of these animations are done but the purpuse of this is to create a constant execution of this so...

is there any posibility to execution a function infinitely?

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite is `while(true){//code}` but `for(;;){//code}` is also possible.  Note that just running code forever is a REALLY bad idea.

Comment: I know the risk about this but the idea is to represent the time as the user is visiting the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function that is fired when the animation ends and just call the animation again.

```
$(function() {
  var animate = function() {
    $('#myAnimation').animate({
      left : '+=20'
    }, 1000, 'linear', function() {
      animate();
    });
  }
  animate();
});
```